# Replacing empty cells with values Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

value1,value2,value3,value4,value5

,,value6,value7,value8

,,value10,value11,value12
```

I would need to insert values in the empty cells.

I am reading the data with pandas like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(file).fillna('yellow', 'blue')
```

any sugestions?

*Update*:
the error is solved
The rows in my csv where an editing mistake.
The main problem is how to write in to the empty cells custom values.

Expected result

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

value1,value2,value3,value4,value5

yellow,blue,value6,value7,value8

yellow,blue,value10,value11,value12
```

actual result

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

value1,value2,value3,value4,value5

NaN,NaN,value6,value7,value8

NaN,NaN,value10,value11,value12
```

*Initial problem* -> Solved

I am getting an error like this:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

Comment: you have 5 columns and at line 5 you have 6 values so due to this It is throwing error

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 empty columns in lines 3 and 4. So, that makes it 6 columns but you have 5 headers. Just delete the first comma like this:

```
,value6,value7,value8,value9
```

For the second question you can try this:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna('yellow')
```

Comment: hah. that was easy. was so focused on filling the empty cells that i missed the counting.
so, how do I write values in my empty cells?
what i have doesn't work. It replaces with NAN not with value

Comment: @Scilla like how? column based?

Comment: yes, could you read my post again? I just updated it

Comment: @Scilla okay, I updated my answer, too. Like in it just select the column name and apply the function to it.

Answer (score 1):

The topmost row of your csv file if the headers and it will determine the number of columns in your data. As you have 5 headers,

col1, col2, col 3, col 4, col 5

The csv reader will expect there to be 5 columns in every subsequent row of data. As such, your 3rd and 4th row in your csv will be invalid and unalbe to be read by the csv reader.

Eg. ,,value6,value7,value8,value9 has a total of 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I need.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file)
hello = data.append({'col1': yello, 'col2': 'blue'}, ignore_index=True)
```

Now I'd need to write it again to the file.